# Is 2 point perspective geometric assumption correct?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

I start by apologizing for my english, I just love math and learning.

---

as an art student, I noticed a relationship while playing with geogebra because I love math, I took my pen and paper to verify it and it seems right, don't you think? Did I do something wrong?

---

You know the 2-point perspective. The lines are straight and the lines of the nearest edge seem proportional. ( it's probably in the cellar behind them )

---

Anyway, instead of explaining with my terrible English, I want to show it with a visual.

> [image: the relationship i encountered in geogebra]

> [image: my analysis, why is that?]

Is it true and if true do you know anything like this?

It really helps my art because knowing it's proportional helps me predict how low the other one will go, how nice. :)

Comment: I noticed that there is an error in the similarity notation.

Comment: I think the argument is basically correct. Though it is not presented in the rigorous manner.